# ngStyle binding not working when using scope variable

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let connection of connections">
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-2'>{{connection.arrivalTime}}</div>
        <div class='col-1'>{{connection.delay}}</div>
          <div class='col-2'>{{connection.actualArrivalTime}}</div>
          <div class='col-1'>{{connection.icon}}</div>
          <div class='col-1'><span [ngStyle]="{'background-color': connection.colors.bg}">{{connection.line}}</span></div>
          <div class='col-3'>{{connection.direction}}</div>
          <div class='col-2'>{{connection.cancelled}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
styleUrls: ['../app.component.css', '../../simple-grid.css'],
})
export class ZVVComponent {


 connections: PublicConnection[] = [];
  displayDate: Date;

  constructor(private zvvService: ZVVService) {

    this.displayDate = new Date();

   zvvService.getConnections(this.displayDate).subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach( (connection) => {
        this.connections.push(new PublicConnection(
          connection.product.line,
          connection.product.longName,
          connection.product.direction,
          connection.cancelled,
          connection.product.icon,
          connection.product.color,
          connection.mainLocation.time,
          connection.mainLocation.countdown,
          connection.mainLocation.realTime.time,
          connection.mainLocation.realTime.countdown,
          connection.mainLocation.realTime.delay,
          connection.mainLocation.realTime.isDelayed,
          connection.mainLocation.realTime.hasRealTime
        ));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, I used ngStyle in one of the divs and want to bind it to the variable connection.colors.bg that contains a hex string of the color:

```
export class Color {
  get fg(): string {
    return this.fg;
  }

  get bg(): string {
    return this.bg;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work and the text remains black and the background white. What am I doing wrong? When I change it, and write red in it instead of the variable, the text shows up in red.

Here is the PublicConnection code:

import { Color } from './color';

```
export class PublicConnection {

constructor(
  public line: string,
  private name: string,
  public direction: string,
  public cancelled: boolean,
  public icon: string,
  public colors: Color,
  public arrivalTime: string,
  private countdown: string,
  public actualArrivalTime: string,
  private actualCountdown: string,
  public delay: string,
  private isDelayed: boolean,
  private hasRealtimeData: boolean
) {
  this.direction = this.direction.replace('&#252;', 'ü');
  this.direction = this.direction.replace('&#246;', 'ö');
  this.direction = this.direction.replace('&#252;', 'ü');
}
}
```

Comment: What is `connections`?

Comment: I added the rest of the component code so that you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the `ngStyle` directive -- you are using that correctly. It is most likely the data not being loaded when the component first tries to render.

Since your data is asynchronous, I'm guessing that at the time the component is rendering and setting the background color, it has not yet received a color from the service.

Try using a safe navigation operator by changing `connection.color.bg` to `connection.color?.bg` in your template.

Read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Didn't change anything. Wouldn't the other content also not render in this case? It's loaded with the same call

Comment: True, it may be wise to use the safe navigation operator anyways, but I guess that isn't what's causing your problem : /. What happens if you make the `bg` getter always return `'red'`?

Comment: Then it's also just black and not red.